# 2 IP Add. One is for Internet/public and another is with IP Security Policy and Windows Firewall Advance (blocking all connection)

Tags: networking, security, firewall

We've hosted a VPS, and we have 2 IP Address. We have made an "IP Security Policy" for allowing lot of IP Ranges and "Windows Firewall Advance for Connection Security Rules" to block all connection (Authentication: Do not Authenticate). We wanted this rule & firewall for First IP Address and the Second IP Address will allow all connection so that we can browse any website, will handle SMTP and other stuff.

The VPS has only single NIC. Is there any way to fix this problem or any other software can you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing my best here to read between the lines...You might consider rewording your question as it is very unclear what your situation is how it is a problem.

You can assign two IP addresses to the same NIC, and there are reasons for doing so. Security usually isn't one of them. Different IPs do not provide a strong barrier of security as an attacker with visibility and accessibility to one IP usually has access to the other. Given that this is a VPS, if you request multiple IPs for the same interface, they will likely be in the same subnet and have the same accessibility from public networks.

If you have different sets of IP ranges that should have different access to services, you are better off making several fine grained firewall rules to allow specific services depending on the origin IP address. Alluding to the principle of least privilege, these specific rules should be layered above a general rule of block all traffic.